# Exception while retriving data from Address Book

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am getting this exception while retriving data from address book. I have check through internet but not get any help for that.

**Overflow allocating bitmap backing store.  Cannot back bitmap with 320 bytes per row, -2147483648 height, and 1 planes**

I am using AddressBook Framework for retriving data from Address Book. is this issue of Memory or it due to getting information of avatar that i have set in Addressbook contact.

Please help. If any suggestion or recommendations for it then please give it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply

As you have said, I have checked all the code for drawing large an image or view. And found the below function that i have used for resizing image. Now resizing image will be done on server side. I have more doubts for this issue. You can check it in below block of code. Now waiting from customer for this issue.

Thanks again for your help.

```
-(NSData *)getCompressedImageDataFromData:(NSData *)imData
{
    NSImage *pImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imData] autorelease];
NSSize orgSize = [pImage size];
int widthInput, heightInput;
widthInput = orgSize.width;
heightInput = orgSize.height;
if(widthInput <= 72 && heightInput <= 72)
    return imData;
double newheight = heightInput;
NSSize   newSize;
if(widthInput >= 72)
{
    double ratio;
    ratio = widthInput / heightInput;
    newheight = 72 / ratio;
    newSize = NSMakeSize (72, newheight);
}
else
    newSize = NSMakeSize(widthInput, newheight);
NSImage *outputImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:newSize] autorelease];

if(![outputImage isValid])
    return nil;

[outputImage lockFocus];

[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];


[pImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
          fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];

[outputImage unlockFocus];
NSData *imageData = [outputImage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionJPEG factor:0];

return [imageData mutableCopy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating one large view or image into which you're drawing multiple contacts in the address book? It sounds like you're trying to create too large an image/view.

Comment: I am preparing just array of 50 contacts which contain details of all information of contact including picture that have been set in contact in addressbook. I converting this contact information in base64 string.

Comment: Exception not generated on Leopard & recently i have also checked on Snow Leopard. But not get this exception again. It only generates on our one customer's pc.

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through your code until you trigger the message. Post the relevant code.

Comment: hi Joshua Nozzi, I have added some code as answer. Please help me what is going wrong?